# RatingBar in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ratingbar

I have a `RecyclerView` that holds a `TextView` and a `RatingBar`. I'm not quite sure where to handle the `setOnRatingBarChangeListener`, should it be handled in the `RecyclerViewAdapter` or some where else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try always to abstract such things through interface, that you can reuse it later and maintain code easily.

You have multiple ways.

Firstly consider common `RecylerView.Adapter` class

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Record> mRecords;
    private OnRecordEventListener mClickListener;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Record> records,OnRecordEventListener listener) {
        this.mRecords = records;
        this.mClickListener = listener;
    }
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            Record record = records.get(i);
            viewHolder.textViewTitle.setText(record.getName());
            viewHolder.ratingBar.setRating(record.getRating());
        }


        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView textViewTitle;
            private RatingBar ratingBar;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
                ratingBar = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar_rating);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I would use interface like this

```
public interface OnRecordEventListener  {
      void onRatingBarChange(Record item,float value);
}
```

Please note , I could make something like that

```
public interface OnRecordEventListener implements OnRatingBarChangeListener
```

But than you will not have you item object (`Record`) passed back to class that implemented this interface, only the way is to `setTag` to `RatingBar` but I think it is bad solution.

And your `Activity`, `Fragment` or any object should implement this interface

When you create `ViewHolder` pass listener into constructor like this.

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecordEventListener listener) {
          super(itemView);
          textViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
          ratingBar = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar_rating);
          bar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
             listener.onRatingBarChange(mRecords.get(getLayoutPosition()), rating);
            }
           }
          });
         }
```

And of course in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
@Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
                return new ViewHolder(v,mClickListener);
            }
```

Also you can do this with setter method in `onBindViewHolder` as you want. I think passing to constructor is good enough.

Another way is to user something like `EventBus` to send event when rating bar changed, but personally for me it is better to use listener approach, `EventBus` is powerful design architecture, but it is hard to debug, and in this case it will be redundant, I think.

**EDIT**

In addition you can use this interface for other events, like button clicks or whatever, you just need to add method into interface,implement it and bind in `ViewHolder` constructor.

**UPDATE**

Consider you are using `RecyclerView` in `Activity`

```
public class RecyclerActivity extends Activity implements OnRecordEventListener {
    // all institutionalization, callbacks, hook methods
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      // Initialization .....
      mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(...);
      // Passing this because this class implements interface
      mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(mRecord,this));
    }
    @Override
    void onRatingBarChange(Record item,float value) {
      // Save your object into database here 
    }
}
```

It depends on your underlying architecture.

1. If you are using `ORM` , so maybe you object is inherited from base ORM Object class ,so maybe it has methods like `save` , `update`
2. If you are saving data directly from `Activity` using `ContentProvider` or `Cursor` you should to do serialization manually and save into db.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Where do I put the code to save the new rating in the database?

Comment: You are welcome, your question about `DB` is not really related to the main question, it depends on your implementation.  
I have updated my answer, please have a look.